# I want to add my electron app to mac's ,share menu extension when any folder is clicked

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaw3O.png) shown code is piece of build.config.json file , I tried to rebuild it using chat gpt's idea but I don't think it is practical solution, is it how it is done ? or is there any way to add my app to share menu extension , can anyone has reference to how i can solve my problem. thank you in advance

```
"mac": {
        "icon": "static/xxx.png", 
        "category": "public.app-category.utilities",
        "target": "dmg",
        "hardenedRuntime": true,
        "gatekeeperAssess": true,
        "extendInfo": {
          "NSAppleEventsUsageDescription": "Let me use Apple Events.",
          "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Let me use the camera.",
          "NSScreenCaptureDescription": "Let me take screenshots.",
          "NSServices": [
          {
            "NSMenuItem": {
              "default": "Share with My App"
            },
            "NSMessage": "shareWithMyApp:",
            "NSSendTypes": [
              "NSStringPboardType"
            ],
            "NSReturnTypes": [
              "NSStringPboardType"
            ]
          }
        ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is write a **[Share Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)** and include it in your bundled app.  In my experience (which may not be the best way to do it) I built a minimal Share extension in xCode and the I included the generated ".appex" package in my built app.  I'm still trying to work out the quirks on my attempt, and it's definitely a much more involved process than just adding some values to the Info.plist.

You'll need to be able to write some code in Swift or Obj-C and the proper design is to have the user validate the selected files and then "share them" with a cloud service in the extension, preferably, independent of the the parent app.

I believe in the iOS version of share extensions the extension is heavily sandboxed with only certain shared resources being available.  You should be able to access shared keychain resources and application group files.

What follows is my dirty method of including a share extension in and electron project on MacOS.  I know others have done it, but this is what I figured out by hacking away at the idea.

I've found that I can share files to an application group folder reachable by both the extension and the parent app.  Unlike iOS, MacOS allows the child app to launch the parent app, although with no arguments.  Having these resources available, I wrote a minimal share extension using the template provided by xCode.

My extension closes the share dialog as if the user had pressed the send button and writes the received URLs out to files in the application group folder.  I believe that this will not be allowed in the App Store, as they'll enforce certain patterns.

My extension simply writes the URLS into files named with UUIDv1 values, allowing me to keep them in the order they were received.  After I write those files out, I launch my app which looks for those same files (on `launch` or `second-instance`) and processes the files using my electron code which I've already written to handle command line arguments.

In addition to writing the code, you'll need to write Info.plist values which help the OS manage your extension. This is the relevant portion in my extensions Info.plist.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ShareViewController</string>
</dict>
```

The extension should also have [a bundle identifier signifying it's a relation to your parent app](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/15712).

You'll also likely want to configure the name and icon for your extension in xCode so that it appears as desired in the menu.

Once the xCode project is built, I copy the generated ".appex" into my electron project (in this case, at the path `includes/mac/universal/PlugIns/Share.appex` and it's part of my electron-builder mac build configuration.  In my electron-builder.json, the relevant entries looks like this.

```
{
  ...
  "mac": {
    ...
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "./includes/${os}/universal/PlugIns",
        "to": "PlugIns"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

At the moment, I'm still trying to get past a few quirky things that prevent my extension from being automatically enabled on the system.

1. The built app has to be run before the extension is recognized by the operating system.
2. The first time I got it to work, it needed to be enabled in `System Preferences > Extensions > Added Extensions` and `System Preferences > Extensions > Share Menu`.  After the first time, these were remembered by the system.
3. While other applications have the extension in their menus after doing this, I had to restart Finder (restart or log out/in) to have it show up in the finder menu.

In regards to your question about specifically targeting folders, I don't have an answer.  [This page in apple's documentation describes configuring the activation rules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes/nsextensionactivationrule), although I don't see anything that would help.  You could filter after your app is selected from the menu, but it would still appear in the menu for non-folder objects.

I hope this made sense and helps you or someone in some way.  The yellow box tells me not to do this, but if someone would be nice enough to teach us a better, less hacky method of implementing a share extension for an Electron app, I would be **very** interested in hearing all about it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking time to answer my question, Honestly when I first read the answer I couldn't get what you meant as you explained instructions since I had no idea how to implement Share extension in Xcode .  After rereading your answer and doing some research on it , finally I get the idea.  I still have problems  to figure out how I can make a communication between Share App Extension and Electron . After all , the idea of writing file to record the shared items is the good one . Thank you again for the excellent response,I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: hey! sorry to bother u again. i am building the xcode project which has a share extension in it with my app but xcode is not generating .appex file. is there any additional pre setups that im doing wrong ? could u catch time to go through the process. thank u so much

Comment: Hi @NastyCarl, I am developing Finder sync extension. I dnt hve any macod, xcode background. I want to create sync status icons badge. How to give custom image path so that it'll take our sync_success image path? How to bundle extension with app? I got appex file which I included in parent folder of electron inside Plugins folder. When I am running electron app, I can see badge icons on the folder I specified in finder sync extension. but how it will communicate with electron? Say I want to update success icon to fail icon. How to do it? Any minor help would be rly helpful for us as we r stuck

Comment: I've never done a Sync Extension, but obviously people are doing communication with their main app.

Here's an article I found about the basic concepts.
https://www.codecentric.de/wissens-hub/blog/finder-sync-extension

I'm pretty sure that to communicate with the app extension you would need to access apples NotificationCenter, you're going to need to get your hands dirty in native javascript modules.  In my experience this meant using Objective-C++, which combines Objective-C (Apple apis) and C++ (interface with node-addon-api).  Javascript would obviously be part of it as well.

Comment: If you go native, I'd recommend you do as much as possible in JS and use the native code as a wrapper layer to Apple's APIs. You'll need to translate between data types going both ways. Using NotificationCenter with observers will probably necessitate using a callback or inheriting from EventEmitter. I chose the latter:

import { EventEmitter } from "events";
import { inherits } from "util";
const NativeModule = require( "../../../build/Release/NativeModule.node" );
inherits( NativeModule.Monitor, EventEmitter );

This allowed me to access emit from the native code.